# Internet accessebility on Blackberry: HttpConnectionFactory and HttpConnection

Tags: blackberry, device, httpconnection

I have created BB application and I have called webservice in this apps . App is working great in Simulator but when I sign application and install app in device. But through HttpConnectionFactory and HttpConnection have problem to get Internet process has been stop after Homescreen. So how can I get internet of my application? Is there any other way to get internet in device? I search a lot about that but I get that this is known issue for blackberry developer. So please tell me how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blackberry is a device which can connect to internet in many many ways. Each of them are specified as a service book. Different types of transports that are possible are WAP, Blackberry Enterprise Service, Blackberry Internet Service, (old) Blackberry Unite, Wi-Fi etc. When you create a network connection, you will need to specify what type of connection you are interested in.

A more detailed information is provided in this article - [Different ways of connecting to internet](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0)